# zip folder in makefile mac

Tags: macos, makefile, zip

I use a makefile on Mac OS X and I try to zip a directory in another folder where my makefile is :

My makefile is in folder : /Volumes/Sources

And the folder to zip is : /Volumes/Bin/myapp

So I try to run zip command in makefile like this :

```
zip -r myapp.zip /Volumes/Bin/myapp
```

It works BUT in my zip archive, I have directories "Volumes", "Bin", "myapp"

And I don't want, I would like all files and folders of /Volumes/Bin/myapp at the root of .zip archive.

I try "pushd" and "cd", abut after changing directory, a "pwd" command shows that i didn't change ! I'm still in /Volumes/Sources

Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each command in a makefile rule acts in its own subshell. This won't work:

```
cd /Volumes/Bin/myapp # <-- you start in Sources/, cd to myapp/, and die.
zip -r myapp.zip . # <-- you are in Sources/, drat!.
```

Try this:

```
cd /Volumes/Bin/myapp ; zip -r myapp.zip .
```